# Fetching data between Start date to end date

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$startMonth = strtotime(2011-02-20);
$endMonth = strtotime(2011-06-05);
while($startMonth <= $endMonth)
{
     echo date('F Y', $startMonth);
     $startMonth = strtotime("+1 month", $startMonth);
}
```

I have a problem while fetching data between start and end date using the code above.
If i run this code it's just able to fetch the data between 02[feb] to 05[april] and the 06[june] is omitted. I just want to know what problem is with my code. If i give the dates as 2011-02-01 to 2011-06-01 the output is generated.

problem is like:

- if i give:  '2011-02-01' to '2011-06-01' it works
- if i give '2011-02-02' to '2011-02-01' **it won't work**
- if i give '2011-02-02' to '2011-02-03' it  works

Comment: You'd probably want to focus on modifying the query that fetching this data, then manipulating a too large data set. Could you show us the query instead?

Comment: its not abt the query part... in the code.... its not able to fetch the date and month....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
$startMonth = strtotime(2011-02-20);
$endMonth = strtotime(2011-06-05);
```

with

```
$startMonth = strtotime('2011-02-20');
$endMonth = strtotime('2011-06-05');
```

You need to clearly set that date is string value, because PHP makes calculation and replaces 2011-02-20 with 1989 (2011 minus 2 minus 20)

---added---

Ok, one more variant (hope I understand what you want to see )

```
<?php
$startMonth = strtotime(date("01-n-Y",strtotime('2011-02-20')));
$endMonth = strtotime(date('01-n-Y',strtotime('2011-06-05')));
  while($startMonth <= $endMonth)
     {
           echo date('F Y', $startMonth);
           $startMonth = strtotime("+1 month", $startMonth);
     }
?>
```

Comment: output: February 2011March 2011April 2011May 2011

Comment: i had removed the variable and just put the date....nor its within single quote''

Comment: modified my answer. Is this what you want to see?

Answer (score 0):

You should remove $ sign at $2011. $2011 to 2011.
That would be solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

```
$startMonth = strtotime(2011-02-20);
        $endMonth = strtotime(2011-06-05);
      while($startMonth <= $endMonth)
         {
               echo date('F Y', $startMonth);
               $startMonth = strtotime("+1 month", $startMonth);
         }
```

You have additional $ where you do not need them.

```
$2011-02-20
```

should be

```
2011-02-20
```

Comment: you're wrong, strtotime(2011-02-20) == strtotime (1989), so $2011-02-20 should be '2011-02-20', not 2011-02-20

Answer (score 0):

*If we consider it a misprint $2011-06-20*
then

$startMonth + 4 month = 2011-06-20

```
2011-06-20 > 2011-06-05
```

so echo **not print** June 2011